# TSQL: Static variables vs. calculations in where clauses

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm working on optimizing some queries and ran into an oddity that I'm not sure how to explain. Using SQL server 2012 with the following code:

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME2 = DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()),
        @enddate DATETIME2 = GETDATE()

SELECT * 
FROM table1 WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE somedate BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
  AND somestate = 'NV'

SELECT * 
FROM table1 WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE somedate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate 
  AND somestate = 'NV'
```

Looking at the actual execution plan, the first select has an index seek and a key lookup, where the second has a clustered index scan. Since the `SELECT`s are essentially identical from a functional purpose, I wasn't sure why there would be the difference in execution plans. My last DBA had told me that declaring variables with value to use in `WHERE` clauses was better than having the calculations in the `WHERE` clause, but this seems to indicate counter to that statement. I'm hoping for any clarification on what causes the large disparity between the two statements. I did try to search for some answers about this, but didn't have much luck, if someone can point me in the right direction, I'd be exceedingly grateful.

Thank you!

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: I guess in the second case the sql server is not aware that startdate and enddate are related, he expects any values, so he choose scan (think of dates years apart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you slightly misunderstood when the use of calculations in the where clause is considered detrimental. Using a calculation which includes the column which would be used for indexing is when you have performance issues because it can't effectively do an index seek on a calculation. In your example the indexing column (somedate) is NOT in the calculation so it shouldn't have a negative impact on your indexing. Refer to [Sql Server Query Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc546506.aspx) for further explanation on SARGs (the issue you are referring to with calculations in the WHERE clause).

If you are viewing the Execution Plan in SSMS I would recommend checking if it suggests any indexes because for the second plan to do a clustered scan as opposed to a seek would make me think you might need to create a more optimal index for your query.

Lastly, if you see a Key Lookup that is generally an indication that your query is NOT optimized ([Key Lookup Showplan Operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326635(v=sql.105).aspx)).

On a non-performance note Microsoft also recommends using >=<= as opposed to between with dates to avoid accidental overlaps, although I don't think this really applies to your situation.

Comment: Thank you Anthony for the info. The initial version of these selects didn't have the somestate as part of the clauses and had extremely similar results to this, insofar as the the variable version did a clustered index scan and the one with the calculation didn't and neither had any suggested indices in the execution plan either, which was more confusing to me since I have no idea how the introduction of a variable would force an index scan. And interestingly enough, the new versions that include the somestate has a missing index on the variable version, but not on the calculated version.